# The edit done from the Community user should be considered as an edit done from another user

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, edit-summary

I took some actions on [Will session work if cookies are disabled on client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859355/will-session-work-if-cookies-are-disabled-on-client-side) which, in the exact order, were:

- Improving a suggested edit
- Voting to close the question, which already had four votes
- Editing a typo in the title

When I edited the title, the edit summary (which I edit to show, "corrected spelling in the title") showed, "insert duplicate link"; that should not have been used as edit summary because that was not the previous edit I did.

What happened is that my improvement to the suggested edit, and my edit to the title were in the grace period, and they are shown as a unique edit in the revision page.

[image: screenshot]

The revision page shows I added the duplicated link at the top of the question, but that is clearly something done from the Community user, once the question has been closed after my vote.

The following situation is similar:

- I edited the tags for a question on Drupal Answers
- I closed the question as duplicate
- I edited the question to add a link to another duplicated question

What the [revision page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/33999/revisions) shows is the following.

[image: screenshot]

That is different from how the [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33999/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-a-different-database-then-the-default) appears. (The previous screenshot, and the following one have been taken in different times; that explains why the timestamps are different.)

[image: screenshot]

If a user edits a question right after I do it, and then I edit again the question, my first, and my last edits are not shown as merged, even if they have done in the grace period. The same should happen when the other user who edits the question is the Community user.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, let me restate the problem: you edit, close, and edit all within the grace period, and the change effected by the community user shows up in your combined change (due to the grace period) in the revision history?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The community user no longer creates an entry in the revision history, so this problem should no longer obtain.